# Creating Bamboo Release automatically after successful build

Tags: bamboo

I am using Bamboo 5.6.2 version.

I have a requirement to create a release every time a build is successful as part of Continuous Integration Pipeline. Output of build pipeline is a link to docker image from an external docker registry.

*Reason being*: Administrator has configured build expiry where old build results may be deleted including artifacts.

*Intent*: Creating a release will ensure that build result/artifact stays and thereby allowing us to deploy it at a later stage by referring to artifact.

I found similar question here: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/33136376/how-can-i-automatically-create-a-deployment-release-but-dont-execute-deployment-yet but yet to be answered.

Answer (score 2):

Create Deployment environment with echo script task and add trigger to that environment to deploy on successful build. Not sure such trigger exists in 5.6, working with 5.14.4